# Benefits of Azure PluralSight

Tags: azure, saas, plural

I am a beginner in the IT world.
I would like to know what are the advantages of doing the Microsoft Azure PluralSight courses? What kind of It jobs could I Apply having this certificate?

Comment: offtopic for stack overflow

Comment: While this is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow, feel free to post this question at the ASP.NET Core Slack: http://tattoocoder.com/aspnet-slack-sign-up/. We have an #azure channel there. That said, your question is a bit broad. If you ask on Slack, maybe you can specify what kind of job you would want to apply for (developer, infrastructure etc.). They may be able to give more suggestions on learning materials as well.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the Azure course on Pluralsight will give you knowledge of the Azure Cloud Computing platform from Microsoft. Azure is typically used for storing databases in the cloud or for deploying applications to a cloud environment or similar tasks.

While many companies look for developers who have experience with cloud platforms like Azure and AWS most often the person who performs Deployments, a task that brings an application from the Development stage to the stage where it is publicly available and usable, specifically specializes in that skill and those tools.

The position where a person is responsible for the deployment, integration, and maintenance of the application is typically called "Dev Ops".